# Creating facebook business page is POSSIBLE but how?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I researched a lot on this subject and on everywhere I've seen, it is stated that creating page with facebook api is not possible. There is one application, [Pagemodo](http://www.pagemodo.com/), which manages that and I don't know how. So how does it manage to create facebook page automatically? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe they have access to a special API – or they are just using some humans in an x-th world country to do it manually in almost real-time :-)

Comment: This is a quest am also trying to solve...
No luck so far