# Facebook API - Create a business page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

It's a highly discussed topic over the globe.
But I haven't found a convincing answer or a solution.
All the SO post finally ended up in a **NO** or a solution with minimum lead.

[How to create a Facebook fan page for a website in an automated way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045584/how-to-create-a-facebook-fan-page-for-a-website-in-an-automated-way)

[Creating Facebook Page programmatically through Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926113/creating-facebook-page-programmatically-through-)
open-graph-api

Finally this one - [Creating facebook business page is POSSIBLE but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359406/creating-facebook-business-page-is-possible-but-how)

[Pagemodo](http://www.pagemodo.com/) does lets you create an actual facebook page(I assume its through Facebook javascript SDK).

According to my knowledge Facebook offers following API/SDK

```
Graph API
FQL
Open Graph
Javascript SDK
Dialogs
Chat
Internationalization
Ads
Public Feed
Keyword Insights
```

Out of these first 4 should possibly define the page creation API

Graph API - doesn't have any query  to POST `pages/create`

FQL - can't insert(ignore anyway)

OpenGraph - Can we have a object of `type:page`

Javascript SDK - Am positive on it, that javascript SDK could help(anyone had luck with it ?)

May I know whether its really possible by any means to create a facebook page ?
Does facebook have any other API that allows to create one ?

Any sort of help appreciated.
Thanks!